# Javascript alert in chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, alert

I have an alert box, and when I run that code in Firefox, no matter what program I have over firefox, firefox appears with the pop-up automatically over other programs open.

This however, does not work in Chrome.

What gives?  Would this be a perference change or this there a line of code that says focus on this window.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:jquery]?

Comment: On the other hand Firefox isn't tagged.

Comment: There is a reason you can't use the word "question" in a title. Please don't circumvent that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used

```
window.blur();
window.focus();
```

and that fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `alert` is browser specific. Unfortunately there is not line of javascript code to change this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have customizable (and working the same in every browser) alert window, use [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal).

Note: It will be over the actual page, not over the (other) window.

Comment: How's this going to help the OP have the browser steal focus from other programs?

Comment: @GGG: It won't, that's impossible.  But this answer would work the same cross-browser.

Comment: @Rocket you mean except for browsers that do steal focus when `alert`ing, right? It sounded to me like the focus-stealing specifically was the behavior the OP wanted.

Comment: @GGG: I'm aware it's what the OP wanted, but some browsers (thankfully) don't allow it, and there's no way around it.  So, with this solution, all browsers will act the same, instead of some acting one way, and some another.